# Magento 2 category list page - add template - get product attribute

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, product-attribute, catalog, products

I want to add a custom template inside the category list page.

Therefore I added the following inside my `catalog_category_view.xml`;

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">

     <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="product-specs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/specs_list.phtml" />

</block>
</block>
```

Inside the `list.phtml` template I load this template using;

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('product-specs') ?>
```

And inside the custom template I loaded the following;

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
```

But I still can not get any product attribute data, so for example the following line gives me a error. `<?php echo $_product->getName();?>`

How can I change this and get the productdata?

UPDATE:

We achieve this in M1 by the following line in the list.phtml template;

```
<?php $this->getChild('product-specs')->setProduct($_product);?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product-specs', false); ?>
```

But it seems that we can not use this in the same way in M2. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I think you have to use loop for this $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); in you template for get product name

Comment: @Jinesh Thanks! I tried that also, but in that case I get the data of all products, inside each individual product. This because we get a loop inside a loop.

Comment: You want get particular product name am I right?

Comment: @Jinesh Well, I want to load additional product attribute data of that specific product. So this template file `<?= $block->getChildHtml('product-specs') ?>` is loaded inside the foreach loop of the `list.phtml` template file.